# Is there a graphical interpretation/proof of the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Tags: calculus

Is there any geometric interpretation of FTC2 that would give me some intuition? Even only an example would help.

Comment: Some texts use a different order for the FTC compared to others. For clarity, which FTC are you talking about?

Comment: Leibniz-Newton Formula  . The formula expressing the value of a definite integral of a given integrable function f over an interval as the difference of the values at the endpoints of the interval of any primitive F of the function f.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$P:\quad a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_N=b$$
be an arbitrary partition of $[a,b]$. Then (telescopic sum and MVT) we have
$$F(b)-F(a)=\sum_{k=1}^N \bigl(F(x_k)-F(x_{k-1})\bigr)=\sum_{k=1}^N F'(\xi_k)\>(x_k-x_{k-1})$$
for certain $\xi_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]$ $\>(1\leq k\leq N)$. It follows that
$$F(b)-F(a)=\sum_{k=1}^N f(\xi_k)\>(x_k-x_{k-1})\in\bigl[L_P(f),U_P(f)\bigr]\ .$$

Since this holds for any partition $P$ it has to be true that in fact
$$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)\>dx\ .$$